# Forcefully Remove Documents from LibreOffice Document Recovery List

Tags: libreoffice

I've been having this issue with LibreOffice where whenever I open it I get the document recovery window below:
[LibreOffice Document Recovery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueg2G.png)

The document it's referring to is unrecoverable and I don't care about its contents. If I click discard, the document recover window closes and libreoffice fails to start. If I click start, the status changes to original document recovered. I then click finish and libreoffice again fails to start. The only way I can get libreoffice to start is by clicking the close button on the top right, but the document recover window will be present again next startup.

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I stop LibreOffice trying to recover unrecoverable documents?

Here are some options:

1. Start LibreOffice with the `--norestore` command line option:

   > `--norestore`    Disables restart and file recovery after a system crash.

   Source [Starting the LibreOffice Software With Parameters - LibreOffice Help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters)
2. Remove any `.~lock.filename.odt#` files.

   Note: these files may be hidden.